# How to properly erase entire block device /dev/xxxx?

Tags: partition, dd, flash-memory

I have a block device that I'm trying to erase using `dd`. Seems like all my portion has been deleted. However, `dd` command is returning `No space left on device`. Block device information is as follows,

```
fdisk -l /dev/xxxx

Disk /dev/xxxx: 7876 MB, 7876902912 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 240384 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 64 * 512 = 32768 bytes

Disk /dev/xxxx doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I use the following `dd` command to erase,

```
~ # dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/xxxx bs=1M count=7876
```

And I get the following output,

```
dd: writing '/dev/xxxx': No space left on device
7513+0 records in
7512+0 records out
7876902912 bytes (7.3GB) copied, 355.751103 seconds, 21.1MB/s
```

Can someone help me understand the output here, please? Output shows `7876902912 bytes (7.3GB) copied`. This is the entire size of the device. Then does it mean that the entire device has been erased and since there is no space left, thus 'No space left on device'? or does it mean something else?

Comment: 7876 * 1 megabyte = 8258584576 bytes as opposed the actual capacity: 7876902912 bytes is 7512 megabytes - the hard drive sloppy use of "megabytes" is at fault here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.

Also, if this is an SSD, a quick `blkdiscard /dev/xxxx` would have had the same effect of making the device return all zeros when you read anything from it, as writing zeros. (I'd recommend you still run blkdiscard on your device, to let the wear leveling know all your blocks can be put into the pool of blocks to be reused for new data and don't have to be kept intact, data wise.)

And if you go for overwriting with zeros, you don't need the slightly awkward `dd` program for writing zeros. `cat /dev/zero > /dev/xxxxx` would have worked just as well. `pv < /dev/zero > /dev/xxxx` does effectively the same, but gives you speed and progress information on the way.